# Python pandas box plot a single column

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to box plot a single column of the dataframe using pandas. However, I got no figure but a text output as shown below:
thanks

```
df.boxplot(column=['crim'])
```

"{'medians': [], 'fliers' [, ], 'whiskers': [, ], 'boxes': [], 'caps': [, ]}

Comment: The output is more than this but unfortunately I could not manage to paste it here.

Answer (score 15):

***versions***

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

print(pd.__version__)
print(sys.version)

0.18.1
2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 29 2016, 11:07:13) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Also got same results with

```
print(sys.version)

3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

---

consider the `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 5), columns=list('ABCDE'))

df.boxplot(return_type='axes');
```

[image]

both

```
df.boxplot(column=['A'], return_type='axes');
```

or

```
df.boxplot(column='A', return_type='axes');
```

return

[image]